# Does the purchaseToken remain the same when a subscription is renewed with Android In-App Billing V3?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Does the purchase token remain the same when a subscription is renewed with Android IAB V3?

Would it be a bad idea to rely on the purchase token as the user's ID on a backend server? (Assume throwing away their data when the subscription expired isn't a big deal)

Answer (score 3):

According to this answer [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29803041/3046504)
it remains the same.

So should be fine to rely on it, keeping in mind that it will be different if the user cancels and then purchases the subscription again.

Comment: If orderId and purchase token remains same, whats the identifier for the renewal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the token remains the same whenever a subscription is renewed.

In the case of downgrade or upgrade, Purchase Token and order_id is newly generated, but in case of renewal, Purchase Token remains the same.