# Using an old token to query Purchases.subscriptions in the Google Play Developer API

Tags: android, google-api

Let's say I have saved the token from when a user has purchased an automatically renewing subscription via Google Play. When that subscription is automatically renewed, can I still use that older, initial token to get the current status of that subscription (via [Purchases.subscriptions: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. That token does not change. You will pass this token in your request to find out if the subscription has renewed or not.
Make sure you do not lose that token otherwise it will be a nightmare to figure out if the user has renewed or not.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if querying for an expired subscription will actually return information on the expired subscription, or will it just return null?

Comment: You always get a response back. It returns a JSON string with the date the subscription expires or if it has been cancelled.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you have saved me some valuable time! :D

Comment: If a subscription lapses, and then some time later that person renews the subscription, do they get a new token, or is it the same 'purchase' with the same token?

Comment: @Brian. If the user lets the subscription lapse, then they will have to purchase a new subscription and that new subscription will have a new token.

Comment: @DimitarDarazhanski: Using Test subscriptions (which auto-renew after 1 day), on subscription renew, the previous purchase token doesn't work anymore. Looks like it changed on subscription auto-renewal. Any ideas why?

Comment: @superbre Have you found the reason why purchase token is not preserved for test subscriptions?

Comment: If orderId and purchase token remains same, whats the identifier for the renewal? I wanted to store all renews and group them by purchaseToken but they will an identifier of their own.

Answer (score 1):

The purchase token changes when user cancels the auto-renewal and restarts the subscription before the current period ends ( turns the auto-renew back on from play store), does upgrades/downgrades, purchases new subscription after an old subscription lapsed + for SOME cases when the order is on hold and the subscription is recovered. Almost sure  Purchases.subscriptions: get response will not contain the new receipt when using the old token in this cases.

> Resignup refers to when a user subscribes, cancels their subscription, and then re-subscribes before the original subscription has expired. Although they have not lost entitlement and the new subscription will be the same as the previous one, they will go through another purchase flow as they are committing to future payments. They will receive a new purchase token and the linkedPurchaseToken field will be set, as in the case of an upgrade or downgrade.

You can read more at [Medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/implementing-linkedpurchasetoken-correctly-to-prevent-duplicate-subscriptions-82dfbf7167da) post here.